# How to use custom settings.xml with GitLab-CI Auto DevOps?

Tags: maven, gitlab, gitlab-ci, buildpack, gitlab-autodevops

I'm using *GitLab CI Auto DevOps* to compile a project based on Maven based in a DinD (docker-in-docker) runner.

CI job start, and buildpack for Maven is correctly detected (based on herokuish).

How can I configure a custom `settings.xml` file without switching to a custom `.gitlab-ci.yml`?

I would like to continue using Auto DevOps.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Because maven needs access to a private repository based on Nexus it is convenient to configure a custom `settings.xml` (and version it with your source code)

The easiest solution is to include a custom `settings.xml`. This feature was included in the corresponding buildpack used by Auto DevOps some time ago, as you can see in this [article from Heroku buildpacks](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/using-a-custom-maven-settings-xml) about "Using a Custom Maven Settings File".

So I defined MAVEN_SETTINGS_PATH variable in `.gitlab-ci.yml` config file:

```
variables:
 - MAVEN_SETTINGS_PATH: ".m2/settings.xml"
```

Then, included the file `settings.xml` in the repository.
**Avoid to include secrets or another sensible information**

#### When using a private maven repository with credentials

Finally, you can define in Gitlab some variables to be used in `settings.xml`. Using Gitlab UI or API add variables for the user, password, and repository url, to be included as environment variables from Gitlab into the job. Then you can use it in `settings.xml` like `${env.VARIABLE_NAME}`

Example of Gitlab-CI configuration file:

```
include:
  - template: Auto-DevOps.gitlab-ci.yml

variables:
    MAVEN_SETTINGS_PATH: ".m2/settings.xml"
    AUTO_DEVOPS_BUILD_IMAGE_FORWARDED_CI_VARIABLES: NEXUS_REPO_USER,NEXUS_REPO_PASSWORD,NEXUS_REPO_URL
```

As a final recommendation, you should avoid to use passwords in environment variables, use native methods from your environment for credentials storage is recommended.

Comment: This even works without GitLab CI Auto DevOps. GitLab substitutes the variables in the settings.xml file with their respective values defined as CI/CD variables from the project settings. You just need to use the ${env.VARIABLE_NAME} notation as described by @gavioto hereabove.